# Check if order id is invalid using Paypal sdk

Tags: node.js, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

If you are familiar with Paypal api, you would know that after the payment gets aprroved you gett redircted to a success page where it has transaction Id peramter for completing the payment.This parameter id can be invalid if the user alter it or it doesn't exists.

When the id is invalid you get this errror [`RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND`](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-INVALID_RESOURCE_ID).

What I want to do is to check if the id exist. I tried using this method but it is still making the error:

```js
const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersGetRequest(orderID);
const order = await client().execute(request);
```

Comment: Seems like an XY problem http://xyproblem.info/ , where X is not clearly explained here

Comment: @PrestonPHX What I am asking is very clear. I want to validate if the id exists **using paypal SDK**. If there no way to do that there its is the answer for my question.

Comment: There is potentially a way to do it but it is not what you should be trying to do, since it won't actually solve the problem you want to solve, and more importantly the problem you want to solve is the wrong problem to be solving and a bad design.

Comment: Can write an answer and tell why it is a wrong problem, including the potential solution?

Comment: No, your question doesn't include anywhere near enough detailed information about what you are doing for such an answer

Comment: What information do you need?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216809/discussion-between-hamza-khuswan-and-preston-phx).

Answer (score 0):

Your edited question makes more sense, you are concerned about a "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND" error after a return from PayPal, and asking how to avoid this error.

A 'Get' request on a bad resource ID will result in the same "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND" error.

Well, that is expected.  Do your Get, and if RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, there you go -- that's the answer to your check -- it's not valid.